# context deadlock switching in a windows service

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is it possible to get a context deadlock switching exception in a windows service?

JD.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "context deadlock switching"?  If there's a deadlock, how do you switch?  What does context have to do with it?

Comment: Basically, any threading exception you can get in a normal app will be possible (even more likely based on usage) in a service.

Comment: Basically, I had a windows application and occasionally I have seen context deadlocking switching exceptions in the debugger. I now moved the code into a service and for some reason the service has died (even though I have try/catch blocks in my code). I am not sure but I think the service could have died as a result of the switching error. But from what I have read, this type of error can occur in UI apps.

Comment: "context deadlocking switching" mkes no sense. I'm sure it means something to you but you need to explain that in terms that are familiar to other developers

Comment: I'm sure he means a context switch deadlock.

Comment: Sorry, I panicked on seeing a comment in my code which should have been "context switch deadlock" and since I am now running the code in a service and not a winforms app, I was inquiring if the deadlock was possible in a windows service.

Answer (score 0):

Check your service ported code and make sure you have removed all UI code such as calls to MessageBoxes.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172233.aspx) ...

> The most common symptom is that a call
>   on an unmanaged COM component from
>   managed code does not return.

Are you calling out to a COM component that takes a long time to return from an [STAThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute.aspx)?  If so, consider using a separate thread to do the call out to the COM component and then marshaling the return value across to the STAThread.

Comment: It is the third party libraries I am using that cause the Context switch deadlock, so I am not sure to check if they are using COM components.